# Search's no_result_page works only sometimes

Tags: search, simple-search

I have this Simple Search Form in my site that looks like this (simplified for the problem's purpose):

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="news" name="recherche" no_result_page="s/e" result_page="s" results="32" search_in="everywhere" status="open" where="any"}
    <input type="search" id="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="on" maxlength="35" value="{exp:search:keywords}">
    <input type="submit">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

When I search for something that *I know doesn't exist*, such as "askjdakjsbfkub", I get redirected to the "s/e" template correctly, displaying an appropriate "no results" message.

However, when I enter a different term that *I know still doesn't exist*, such as "test", I get redirected to the ugly, god-forsaken default message (pardon my french, literally):

[image]

Can somebody explain that weird behavior? Better yet, anyone has a solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

When you search for something that does have a search result, are you redirected to the correct search results page? You are searching everywhere , search_in="everywhere", which includes comments and all other fields. Could it be possible that "test" was somewhere else in there?

Also, your result_page parameter is set to "s", you might need to try and set it to "s/index".

Comment: There is no comments on any entries, as they are disabled. the `channel="news"` part has been simplified as in reality it's `channel="news|articles|locations"`. I use `search_in="everywhere"` because the channels have different fields with different names, all relevant to the search. Thanks for `result_page="s"`, but my search results are displaying fine. It's just the `no_results` that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After you, other people were asking the same thing. An answer has been found and reported here: [Simple Search returns System Message template for No Results even when 'no_result_page' set](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/simple-search-returns-system-message-template-not)