# Simple Search returns System Message template for No Results even when 'no_result_page' set

Tags: search, system-messages

I’m running into some issues when my users are searching using Simple Search and get no results. For some reason, they’re being redirected to a system message which is detailing they don’t have any results. However, this isn’ the correct template, and certain embeds are showing that shouldn’t be, and as a result are not rendering properly. The search form is inside of a snippet called `snip_primary_nav`, shown here:

```
<nav id="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/HeirloomMeals"><img src="/assets/images/youtube_16.png" alt="Youtube" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/HeirloomMeals"><img src="/assets/images/twitter_16.png" alt="Twitter" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/rss/"><img src="/assets/images/rss_16.png" alt="RSS" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
        {!-- <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/heirloom-meals"><img src="/assets/images/linkedin_16.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="16" height="16" /></a></li> --}
        <li><a href="http://pinterest.com/heirloommeals"><img src="/assets/images/pinterest_16.png" alt="Pinterest" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/heirloommeals"><img src="/assets/images/instagram_16.png" alt="Instagram" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/HeirloomMealsWithCaroleMurko"><img src="/assets/images/facebook_16.png" alt="Facebook" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>          
    </ul>

{exp:search:simple_form channel="blog|shows|recipes|products" search_in="everywhere" where="all" result_page="search/" no_result_page="search/no_results" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}

<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100" />
<input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" />

{/exp:search:simple_form}
<div class="question-call-to-action"><span>Questions?</span><br />Call 413-298-0173</div>
</nav>
```

This is called inside of a general template, but happens on every template similarly:

```
{embed="_includes/.header"}
    <header>
{gv_logo}
{snip_ribbon}
{snip_primary-nav}
    </header>
  <div id="container">
        <div id="banner">
        <h2 id="sig">With Carole Murko</h2>
            <div id="slider">
            {lv_home_headers}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        <section id="col1">
            <h1>{lv_home_col1_heading}</h1>
            <div class="divide">
            {lv_home_col1_content}
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="col2">
            <h2>{lv_home_col2_heading}</h2>
            <div class="divide">
            {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_home_col2_content"}
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="col3">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <article class="highlight">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" category="16" disable="member_data|pagination"}
                <h3><a href="{title_permalink='blog/'}">{title}</a></h3>{exp:replace_plus find="class=:QUOTE:highlight:QUOTE:"}{body}{/exp:replace_plus}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            </article>
            {gv_subscribe}
        </section>
        </div>
  </div> <!-- end of #container -->
{gv_footer}
{snip_footer}
```

I thought maybe I had an open search tag like Adam Wiggall did in this post: ([Incorrect no_results page returned for simple search](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10470/incorrect-no-results-page-returned-for-simple-search)) but after a quick search, I don’t see any other tags that aren’t closed.

Has anyone run into this sort of issue before? My template revisions are off, using files, and templates are synced with files.

Comment: Have you tried to open the templates right on URL?

Comment: Yes. The template loads just fine. :(

Comment: Please, how are the embeds showing if the users are being redirect to a system message? Please, give us more details.

Comment: You are looking at the snippet, right above. There isn’t much more to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I prefer to see the templates of the search group, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in EE's native Search module. Bug reported here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19828

Here's the fix:

Starting in line 1290 of system/expressionengine/modules/search/mod.search.php

REPLACE

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0 OR $query->row('total_results')  == 0)
{
  return ee()->output->show_user_error('off', array(lang('search_no_result')), lang('search_result_heading'));
}
```

WITH

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0 OR $query->row('total_results')  == 0)
{           
  if ($query->row('no_result_page') == "")
  {
    return ee()->output->show_user_error('off', array(lang('search_no_result')), lang('search_result_heading'));
  }
  else
  {
    $path = reduce_double_slashes(ee()->functions->create_url(trim_slashes($this->_meta['no_result_page'])).'/'.$hash.'/');
    ee()->security->restore_xid();
    return ee()->functions->redirect($path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Just the fix I was looking for. Thank you, kindly, Stephen!

Comment: It looks like this fix got reverted sometime between versions 2.7 and 2.10, as it's no longer part of the source code.