# Simple search form results template displays system message template

Tags: simple-search

It seems I have a similar problem to the one described in [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/simple-search-returns-system-message-template-not).

You enter a search query and get redirected to the correct URL but the page displays the system message template saying *Your search did not return any results* instead of redirecting to the no-results template.

Removing the `exp:search:search_results` tag causes the page to render correctly, but obviously without any search results in it. `{exp:search:total_results}{total_results}{/exp:search:total_results}` also shows up as 0.

So why doesn't EE redirect to the no-results template if there are no results? Although it doesn't seem to matter what I enter, I get the error message each time.

### Template code

#### Form

```
{exp:search:simple_form
    channel="blog"
    no_result_page="{segment_1}/search/no-results"
    result_page="{segment_1}/search/results"
    search_in="everywhere"
    where="all"
}
<input type="text" name="keywords">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

#### Results

```
<p>There were <strong>{exp:search:total_results}{total_results}{/exp:search:total_results}</strong> results for a search for <em>{exp:search:keywords}</em>.</p>

<ul class="search-results">
{exp:search:search_results}
    <li>
        <a href="{auto_path}/">{title}</a>
    </li>
{/exp:search:search_results}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in EE's native Search module. Bug reported here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19828

Here's the fix:

Starting in line 1290 of system/expressionengine/modules/search/mod.search.php

REPLACE

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0 OR $query->row('total_results')  == 0)
{
  return ee()->output->show_user_error('off', array(lang('search_no_result')), lang('search_result_heading'));
}
```

WITH

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0 OR $query->row('total_results')  == 0)
{           
  if ($query->row('no_result_page') == "")
  {
    return ee()->output->show_user_error('off', array(lang('search_no_result')), lang('search_result_heading'));
  }
  else
  {
    $path = reduce_double_slashes(ee()->functions->create_url(trim_slashes($this->_meta['no_result_page'])).'/'.$hash.'/');
    ee()->security->restore_xid();
    return ee()->functions->redirect($path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Given that you posted exactly the same answer on the other thread, can we close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: Yeah, of course. But the other one needs at least an up vote first.

Comment: Done. @Tyssen let me know if Stephen's answer doesn't solve your problem and we can reopen this question.

Comment: Not quite. That fixes the system template error issue, but I'm still ending up at the results template with it saying that there are 0 results instead of the no-results template. Should I be following this up with EllisLab instead?

Comment: Definitely chime in on the bug report linked above.

Comment: I've updated the answer, specifically the `else`.