# Custom no results page not showing, shows default page

Tags: search, simple-search, no-results

I am trying to get a custom no search result page working and all I keep getting is the standar white background/ gray box with the text,

```
Search Results:
Your search did not return any results.
Return to Previous Page
```

My code for my simple search form is as follows:

```
<div class="search_box search_results_page">
                {exp:search:simple_form channel="recipes" id="recipe_search" result_page="recipes/search-result"  no_result_page="recipes/no-results" }
                    <span class="search_box_content">
                        <label for="keywords">Search:</label> 
                        <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" class="clear_default" value="Search for a recipe" size="18" maxlength="100">
                        <input id="recipe_submit" type="submit" value="" class="submit">
                    </span>
                {/exp:search:simple_form}
            </div>
```

The template DOES exist and lives in the same template.group as the search template.

I have also looked at this thread: [Simple Search returns System Message template for No Results even when 'no_result_page' set](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/simple-search-returns-system-message-template-for-no-results-even-when-no-resul)

But that doesn't seem to have helped me either, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ee() in /home/sites/justmilk.com/public_html/dev.justmilk.com/jmadmin/expressionengine/modules/search/mod.search.php on line 1262
```

I am fairly new to EE so any ideas hints tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of EE are you running?

Comment: It is an older version, 2.3.1. We want to update the system but finding time to upgrade and test is proving difficult at present. We just need a fix until such a time can be set aside to upgrade the site.

Comment: In that case you need to use `$this->EE` instead of `ee()` when trying the bug fix from the bug tracker. I added an answer -- hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My No Results Page had this code, which is incorrect:

```
{exp:search:search_results}

    <p>We have been unable to find any results for '{exp:search:keywords}'</p> 

{/exp:search:search_results}
```

I found the answer I was looking for here:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/242817/

By using this code:

```
Sorry, there are no results for '{exp:search:keywords} {exp:search:keywords} {/exp:search:keywords}'
```

This fixed the error. All that is left to do is clean up my template.